# Undefined variable: products in @foreach

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

**I'm facing some issues with a project build with Laravel**

i want to show more then ***12 product*** but i don't know what to change. this show only ***12 product*** and i want ***60 product*** to show. please help me. I've tried many solutions but its not working.

```html
                            
<div class="products-box-bar p-3 " >
    <div class="row sm-no-gutters gutters-5">
                                @foreach ($products as $product)
                                    
        <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6" >
            <div class="product-box-2 bg-white alt-box my-md-2" style="border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;border-radius: 8px;">
                <div class="position-relative overflow-hidden">
                    <a href="{{ route('product', $product->slug) }}" class="d-block product-image h-100 text-center" tabindex="0">
                        <img class="img-fit lazyload" src="{{ asset('frontend/images/placeholder.jpg') }}" data-src="{{ asset($product->thumbnail_img) }}" alt="{{ __($product->name) }}">
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-btns clearfix">
                            <button class="btn add-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" onclick="addToWishList({{ $product->id }})" type="button">
                                <i class="la la-heart-o"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn add-compare" title="Add to Compare" onclick="addToCompare({{ $product->id }})" type="button">
                                <i class="la la-refresh"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn quick-view" title="Quick view" onclick="showAddToCartModal({{ $product->id }})" type="button">
                                <i class="la la-eye"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-md-3 p-2">
                        <h2 class="redbaba">
                            <a href="{{ route('product', $product->slug) }}" class="product-title p-0 text-truncate-2" >
                                                    @if(home_base_price($product->id) != home_discounted_base_price($product->id))
                                                        
                                <img class="sale654" src="{{ route('home') }}/ufo/img/sale.png"></img>
                                                    @endif
                                                        {{ __($product->name) }}
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="price-box">
                            <span class="product-price strong-600" style="display: block;">{{ home_discounted_base_price($product->id) }}</span>
                                                    @if(home_base_price($product->id) != home_discounted_base_price($product->id))
                                                        
                            <del class="old-product-price strong-400">BDT&nbsp;{{ home_base_price($product->id) }}</del>
                                                @if (\App\Addon::where('unique_identifier', 'club_point')->first() != null && \App\Addon::where('unique_identifier', 'club_point')->first()->activated)
                                                        
                            <span class="clubpoint02">⛬&nbsp;Point&nbsp;{{ $product->earn_point }}</span>
                                                @endif                                                      
                                                    @endif
                                                
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="djhfgj">
                                                    {{ __($product->shipping_type) }} shipping
                                                </h2>
                        <div class="star-rating star-rating-sm mt-1" >
                                                    {{ renderStarRating($product->rating) }}
                                                </div>
                        <p class="numberofsale">{{ __($product->num_of_sale) }} Sold</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                                @endforeach
                            
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav aria-label="Center aligned pagination" >
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center" style="background-color: #fff;padding: 10px 0;border-radius: 10px;margin-top: 15px;">
                                    {{ $products->links() }}
                                </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: can you post your controller as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your App\Http\ProductsController.php or whichever file you use in fetching products from the database, you should see a function `paginate(12)`, change it to `paginate(60)`

Comment: ProductsController.php there ar 2 of them but none of the show 'paginate(12)'

Answer (score 0):

The title of your post is a little confusing as it doesn't match your description, I'll do my best to help though!

---

**Undefined Variable: $products**

This will most likely be due to the controller not passing a variable to the blade template.

In your controller, make sure that you are passing the variables to the view like so:

```
public function index() {
    // Your logic here
    return view('my-index', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

---

**Pagination Limits**

Displaying 12 items rather than 60 will be due to the limits passed to the `paginate()` function within the controller. Make sure you have set this to `60`

```
public function index() {
    // Retrieve up to 60 products at a time
    $products = Product::paginate(60);

    return view('my-index', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

---

**Forelse loops**

You may want to consider using a `@forelse` loop rather than a `@foreach` loop in case you don't have any products being returned from the query

```
@forelse($products as $product)
   // Display your products
@empty
   // Display a message saying no products were found
@endforelse
```